# How to get date with 4-digit year or date/datetime object from get_date method in tkcalendar.Calendar?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkcalendar

The code I currently have is given as such, and basically what I want to do at the end of this is to get a datetime object which I will be using to query a database.

```
from tkcalendar import *
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date

def capture():
    sample = cal.get_date()
    print(sample)
    print(type(sample))

cal = Calendar(root, selectmode='day', year=2020, month=11, day=22)#just default
cal.pack(pady=20)

myButton = Button(root,text='See Date',command=capture)
myButton.pack(pady = 20)
```

When I run this code and pick a random date, `print(sample)` shows `11/11/20` and `print(type(sample))` shows `<class 'str'>`
I want this method or some other method to get the date with the 4-digit year instead so I can parse it into a date or datetime object, because I'll working with dates from past and future centuries. Or if I can just directly get the date or datetime object that would be good too. How do I go about that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `date_pattern` option to `Calendar(...)`:

```
cal = Calendar(root, selectmode='day', year=2020, month=11, day=22, date_pattern="m/d/y")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works too. I just used a DateEntry class coz the get_date() method for DateEntry returns a datetime.date instance instead of a string so I don't need to do any string to date parsing. But thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. Instead of using a Calendar class, I used a DateEntry class. Basically just replace `cal = Calendar(root, selectmode='day', year=2020, month=11, day=22)` with `cal = DateEntry(root, selectmode='day', year=2020, month=11, day=22)`, leaving everything else identical. I like the format more as well. Thanks to those who responded